# Problems creating a new table with the InnoDB engine. No problems with MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb

I cannot create a table using InnoDB engine. The rest of my tables are using InnoDB without any issues.

Create table statement:

```
USE aps_cmdb;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS servers_services(
  server_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  service_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  created_by INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  modified_by INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (server_id, service_id)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

If I drop the table and retry with engine=innodb:

```
USE aps_cmdb;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS servers_services(
  server_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  service_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  created_by INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  modified_by INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (server_id, service_id)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I get an `errno 150`.

If I re-create it using the MYISAM engine and try to convert it to InnoDB:

`ALTER TABLE servers_services ENGINE = InnoDB;`

I get the following error:

`Error on rename of './aps_cmdb/#sql-5241_3dae' to './aps_cmdb/servers_services' (errno: 150) SQL5.sql 1 1`

I also viewed all foreign keys in the existing database and there is no mention of servers_services. Since I do not create foreign keys in my create statement, I doubt this would have any impact when creating the table.

I didn't have any problems converting other stray MyISAM tables to InnoDB.

**Update #1**

The output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'inno%'`

```
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 1048576
innodb_autoextend_increment 8
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_size 8388608
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_concurrency_tickets  500
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    /mysql/path/here
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_io_threads  4
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
innodb_flush_method 
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  1048576
innodb_log_file_size    5242880
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   ./
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  90
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1
innodb_open_files   300
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    ON
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_spin_loops  20
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_thread_concurrency   8
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_use_legacy_cardinality_algorithm ON
```

**Update #2**

If I run this:

`select * from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%service%';`

I get this:

`(null) aps_cmdb2   servers_services    BASE TABLE  InnoDB`

**Update #3**

I had three files on disk, after having created the table using MyISAM:

1. servers_services.frm
2. servers_services.MYI
3. servers_services.MYD

I dropped the table and none of those files were present on disk. I attempted to create the table with InnoDB and I still got an error.

Comment: Scratch my previous comment ;) [removed]. So, you actually have some tables using InnoDB engine, but can't create/alter only this one?

Comment: Correct, that's exactly what is happening. MyISAM isn't a problem, but I need it to be InnoDB.

Comment: (1) Try checking the filesystem (physical location) where this table should be created. Maybe there is a file already matching this table name, but it is not listed in the tablespace... (2) Also, It is kinda weird that it tries to rename the file to 'servers_services' (without any extension). Can you show us innodb configuration? (`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'inno%'`)

Comment: Ok, you have `innodb_file_per_table` on, which means every table gets its own tablespace. Check that folder and see if there are any files starting with "servers_services"?

Comment: @poncha I have aps_cmdb2 that has an InnoDB table with the same name though... see Update #2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48294/discussion-between-poncha-and-tekiusfanatikus)